# Как сделать, чтобы консоль не закрывалась. Завершение процесса только после нажатия кнопки

Tags: python

```
print('Hello world')
```

Как сделать, чтобы консоль не закрывалась, а выводилось 'Нажмите Enter для выхода'.

Comment: как вы запускаете скрипт, что у вас консоль закрывается? Пример кода в вопросе не закрывает существующую консоль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from msvcrt import getch
key=msvcrt.getch()
if key==b'\r':
    sys.exit(n)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toor/1.py", line 34, in <module>
    from msvcrt import getch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'

Answer (score 1):

```
print('Hello world')
input('Нажмите Enter для выхода\n')
```

**UPDATE:**

```
try:
    from msvcrt import getch
except ImportError:
    import sys
    import tty, termios
    def getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

def stop(symbol, message):
    while True:
        print(message)
        if getch() == symbol:
            break


print('Hello World')
stop(b'\r', 'Press Enter to exit') # Первым параметром нужный вам символ
```

Comment: А если определённую клавишу?

Answer (score 0):

```
# >>>ord('a')
# >>>99 
# >>>ord ESC == 27
print("press 'Esc' to quit...")
from msvcrt import getch
key=getch()
if ord(pressedKey) == 27:    
   sys.exit()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Это дубликат существующего ответа по сути: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752831/1365